# HTML5: is it a valid notation for any tag to be condenses such as <div/>

Tags: html

Using angular directive, I often have to write tags as follows:

```
<div ng-custom-directive-attr="xxxx"></div>
<span ng-custom-directive-attr="xxxx"></span>
```

Is it OK to write them as follows?:

```
<div ng-custom-directive-attr="xxxx"/>
<span ng-custom-directive-attr="xxxx"/>
```

If yes, do all major browsers comply with that?

As a side note, one usually write <img/>, and I never saw <img></img> (or seldom seen).

Comment: I don't think ANY browsers support that.

Comment: Not all tags can be compressed.

Comment: That is XHTML syntax, not HTML5. There are no self-closing tags at all in HTML5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be browsers that support it (though I doubt that), but it's definitely not valid markup.

If you run this through the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it is not happy.

### Input

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>blah</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-custom-directive-attr="xxxx"/>
        <span ng-custom-directive-attr="xxxx"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Output:

[image: W3 Validator output when fed the code above.]